# Darood Ibrahimi

Tags: reciting, darood

I have been listening Darood Sharif on youtube and I have notice reciter say Muhammadin and other reciter say Muhammadiv.

As non Arab I am just stuck here. Kindly help to correct me.
Jazakallah